# Count most frequent words in a database

Tags: r

I have a database named `df` that looks like this :

```
Message
c("This","is,"some","kind","of","message")
c("Another","message")
```

What would be the best way to count the most frequent word in the database? If I do `sort(table(df$Message[1]), decreasing=T)` I get the most frequent word for the first line.

Should I `paste` all the rows into a giant one and use the same formula? The dataframe has 20k+ rows so this doesn't seem very efficient.

edit : To add to my question, I got this database using strsplit, at first it looked like this :

```
Message
"This is some kind of message"
"Another message"
```

Comment: If you got it via `strsplit` it means you now have a list. Then you can use `sort(table(unlist(your_list)))`

Comment: I still see it as a dataframe, this is how i used `strsplit` : `df$Message <- strsplit(df$Message," ",fixed=T)
`

Comment: Then you have a list-column. Try `sort(table(unlist(df$Message)))`

Comment: That did it, thanks !